# Terminate the request from being processed after a timeout in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, server, request

I have an API, which lets say sometimes goes into an infinite loop. I have set a timeout of 30seconds in the spring boot which responds back to the client after 30seconds, but this doesn't stop that particular request from being processed. It still goes on in the background.
Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried @Timed & @Transactional(timeout = 1000)?

Comment: @VinhNT it didn't work